# Google DataTable: Return a column object

Tags: javascript, datatable, google-datatable

I am using the google datatable object to create google visualizations. I would like to read a datatable and then create multiple subtables from that original object.

According to the google documentation there is not a method to "getColumn."

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#DataTable

I know there is a cols property but I am not sure exactly what this property is used for. Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this, and explain what the cols property is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like making views from the original datatable is what you are looking for.  Check out this link:

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#DataView

There its also a description of the cols property on that page.